# Elegant Way Of Displaying Entries Of SQL Table With 30 Colums?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

**Description**

SQL Table "Parameters"

```
     | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | ... | ... | ... | Col28 | Col29 | Col30 |
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------
     | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  | ... | ... | ... |  ...  |  ...  |  ...  |
```

Consists of 30 Colums - ID and 29 Parameter Columns.

I use the following to retrieve the data:

```
 DataSet Data = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
 SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection();
 Connection.ConnectionString = StaticConnectionString;

 Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Parameters WHERE ID='"+ID+"'",Connection);
 Adapter.Fill(Data);
 DataList.Add(Data);
```

Which successfully Retrieves all the data (Rows) from SQL Database with the given ID.

**The problem:**

Simply ***using GridView to display all the data would create unreadable table with a lot of horizontal scrolling***, furthermore, I only want to display 1 Row at time and display other Rows via utilizing Next and previous Buttons.

**Question**

What would be the most elegant and practical way of displaying all the data so it can be readable without horizontal scrolling?

Would it be possible to somehow display table this way:

```
     | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
     -----------------------------
     | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  |
     -----------------------------

     //Columns from 5 to 26 

     -----------------------------
     | Col27| Col28| Col29| Col30|
     -----------------------------
     | ...  | ...  | ...  | ...  |
     -----------------------------
```

Comment: maybe something like this hide and show some columns 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Comment: you can also do manual programming and write your own layout instead of just doing out of the box binding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only displaying a single record at a time, you should likely use

`label:  value`

rather than columns. A generic form interface.